# Add multiple values to array through function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make a function which accepts a value and echo them in the end.

Here's an example:

```
function number_of_files ($name) {
    $name_of_files = array($name);
    var_dump ($name_of_files);
}
```

And I'm using this function as

```
number_of_files("file.png");
number_of_files("audio.mp3");
```

I'm expecting the following output:

```
  Array (
    [0] => file.png
    [1] => audio.mp3
)
```

Any suggestions why is it not working?

Comment: What are you going to use this function for? I don't think this is what you actually want to do.

Comment: Maybe, it's a good case for using a class with a static array?

Comment: every time when you can avoid using static properties.

Comment: @bassxzero I actually wanted to use $name_of_file as multidimensional array. With name and path of the file.

Comment: @splash58 mind suggesting me a good tutorial on classes? Cheers!

Comment: @DevAggarwal You can start with http://php.net/manual/en/book.classobj.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You are overwrite your `$name_of_files` every time. That variable in the functions scope.

Use this:

```
function number_of_files ($name, &$name_of_files) {
    array_push($name_of_files, $name);
}

$name_of_files = number_of_files('file.mpg', $name_of_files);
$name_of_files = number_of_files('audio.mp3', $name_of_files);
var_dump ($name_of_files);
```

Now you are using your array as a reference.

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to overwrite your original array, you can return:

```
function number_of_files ($name, $name_of_files) {
    array_push($name_of_files, $name);
    return $name_of_files;
}
```

But let's note, in the second case I did not used the `&` sign before the `$name_of_files` function argument. That is the reference marker.

You can read it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: What if he doesn't want to update the array passed into the function? What if he is looking to update a static array inside the function?

Comment: then push and return.

Comment: And if he didn't actually want to return anything? Say he just wanted the array to be accessible, with the correct values, inside the function body?

Comment: My answer is point to the scope issue. If after this OP can not handle what he/she wants, I am so sorry. You have the possibilities to write your own answer, or you can ask him/her, what he/she really need.

Comment: @vaso123  "or you can ask him/her, what he/she really need." that's my point. I did ask him, and you posted your answer before he answered.

Comment: @bassxzero Let's see the desired output. It's so clean. I've ended this discussion.

Comment: @vaso123 this actually worked. I'm using $name_of_files as a global variable though. Thanks!

Comment: @bassxzero going through the comments and rest of discussion, I think I should use class instead of a function. But anyway, I'm going to look for OOP now. Thanks you anyway.